# Magento 2: Change design and HTML of menu

Tags: magento2, topmenu

I want to create a different menu for a new theme with different html structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the **solution** so I am answering it.

- Menu content in M2 is generated from *Block* - **vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php**
- To make changes in HTML structure, we need to override the Block in our custom Package Module say *app/code/Mypackage/Mymodule/Block/Html/Topmenu.php*

  **Sample code to override**

  ```
  <?php

  namespace Mypackage\Mymodule\Block\Html;

  class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu

  {
      // your custom methods
  }
  ```
- Override above file through *app/code/Mypackage/Mymodule/etc/di.xml*:

  ```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Mypackage\Mymodule\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
  </config>
  ```
- Make desired changes in the HTML of Menu and css as needed.

Comment: Could you explain what goes into the di.xml ?